# Distinct Query?

Tags: linq

I have a table that contains a Column with client names.  It has about 10-15 distinct clients that appear multiple times in the column.  Is there a way that I can run a query that will list all the distinct clients and do the count for each client so that it shows how many times each client appears in the column?  I know that in SQL you can use as to assign temporary column, but I'm new to LINQ and have no idea if this is possible.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Imagine, you have two absolutely different clients with the same name. What you think about it?

Answer (score 5):

Just like the SQL where you would use a `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`, like this:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*)
FROM customers
GROUP BY name
```

in LINQ you would use `GroupBy(...)` and `Count()`, like this:

```
var res = src.Clients
    .GroupBy(c => c.Name)
    .Select(g => new {
        Name = g.Key
    ,   Count = g.Count()
    });
```

Comment: +1 for solution, of course, but also the explanation about the similarity. =)

Answer (score 3):

I assume `items` contains elements that has a `ClientName`

Use Linq `GroupBy` method.

```
var result = (from item in items
              group item by item.ClientName 
              into g  // g is the group
              select new 
              {
                  ClientName = g.Key,  // g.Key contains the key of the group ;) -> here the common "ClientName"
                  Count = g.Count()  // g is an enumerable over the elements of the group, so g.Count() gives you the number of elements in the group
              });
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

Query syntax:

```
from r in someTable
group r by r.ClientId into grp
select new
    {
        ClientId = grp.Key,
        Occurrences = grp.Count(),
    }
```

As method syntax:

```
someTable
    .GroupBy(r => r.ClientId)
    .Select(grp => new
        {
            ClientId = grp.Key,
            Occurrences = grp.Count(),
        });
```

Where `ClientId` is the column you want to distinct by.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

Pure **linq**:

```
var query = from item in list
            group by item.name into gr
            let count=gr.Count()
            orderby count
            select new {Value = gr.Key, Count=count }
```

With **lambda expressions**:

```
var query= entity.GroupBy(s=>s.Name).
                  Select(x=> new {Value = x.Key,Count=x.Count()}).
                  OrderBy(s=>s.Count);
```

Read more about linq here: [`Linq Samples`](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b).

And by the way, you should search more before asking something.

Comment: Oh, I also meant to comment - the top example is called "query syntax", the second is "method syntax".